# How to install gcc in virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, pip, virtualenv

Having problem getting gcc to install in a virtualenv. If I were using a conda virtualenv the command would be:

```
conda install gcc
```

But when I attempt in a regular virtualenv with:

```
pip3 install gcc
```

I get the following error:

```
Collecting gcc
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gcc (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gcc
```

Pip was upgraded to 9.0.1 with:

```
 pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Is there a pip3 install equivalent for conda install command? Thanks

Comment: `gcc` isn't a Python package.

Comment: @Jim see my edit. Do you know of an equivalent pip3 command statement?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot install gcc in virtualenv — gcc is not a Python package. And you don't need to — Python virtual environments are used to separately install Python packages so you don't need a separate gcc in a virtual env.

If you really need to install a separate, non-system gcc, you probably need bigger virtualization solution — a container or a virtual machine.

Comment: I am trying to install some package(lz4, pandas) in python virtual environment in a docker container. But it is failing with error gcc. If i am not using virtual env then the packages are getting installed successfully. How can i resolve this issue.. packages failing for gcc under virtual env

Comment: If it's already in a docker container then just install gcc normally in the docker image.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a pretty old question, but bumping in if anyone gets caught here. Now, we could install gcc/g++ in a virtual conda environment using the following command. To install GCC:

```py
conda install -c conda-forge gcc
```

and to install G++:

```py
conda install -c conda-forge gxx
```